# Using the redis-stack in the Spring

Tags: redis

I would like to use Redis data through Lettuce in Spring. My Redis is currently using JSON-type data with redis-stack. Is there a way to use JSON.GET through Lettuce?

I also attempted to change it to HASH type from JSON, but I kept Redis in JSON type because I need to use other functionalities like FT.SEARCH. Since it's not possible to retrieve JSON using the general core command 'get,' I'm leaving this question here.